# Помогите пожалуйста сделать print(c)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a=(input(50))
b=(input(12))
c=str((a**2+b**2)**0.5)
print(c)
```

Добавил код, нужно выполнить действия, указанные в c, чего-то не получается. До мозга костей гуманитарий просит помощи!)

Comment: У input параметр предназначен для указания подсказки, которую увидит пользователь, например `a=input("Введите a: ")`. Далее, введенные числа нужно преобразовать в целые или числа с плавающей точкой (в зависимости от того, что у вас там по заданию), `a=float(input("Введите a: "))`. Результат в str не обязательно преобразовывать.

Comment: Вроде разобрался, спасибо большое!